# Xcode : Accessing method instance from other class file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods

I've reasonable successfully setup access to another method in the following way:

SomeScript.m (the class I am trying to access)

```
-(void)amethod{....
```

codeA.h  (the class that is accessing amethod) within the {} has:

```
SomeScript* myScript;
```

codeA.m

```
myScript = [[SomeScript alloc] init];
[myScript amethod];
```

What I want to do however is make it an instance variable of the app delegate but when I put the  SomeScript* myScript; and the myScript = [[SomeScript alloc] init]; in AppDelegate.h the codeA.m does not recognise it.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do? Do you want to create an instance variable of SomeScript in your app delegate?

Comment: Do you want to create an instance of `SomeScript` in `AppDelegate` and access it in `codeA`? Also, do you have access to the `AppDelegate` in `codeA`?

Comment: Yes I want to create an instance of the script so I can access the method 'amethod' from any other class across the program. I'm not sure what you mean by having access to the 'AppDelegate' from codeA (sorry I'm quite new to this but learning fast) can it have access from just importing the .h file to codeA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a property `myScript` to `AppDelegate`:

In AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) SomeScript *myScript; // Add this line

//...

@end
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation PCAppDelegate

@synthesize myScript; // Add this line

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.myScript = [[SomeScript alloc] init]; // Add this line

//...

@end
```

Now that you have declared and initialized the property, you can use it like the following from other classes:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate.myScript aMethod];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - I've tried both methods. The first option gives the error 'property appDelegate not found on object of type "codeA *"' and the second method gives 'Property myscript not found on object of type AppDelegate *' does that give anything away that I'm not doing right?

Comment: @lukedom89 - See my edited answer. I explained how you can add the property to the app delegate.

Comment: @sch I know this question was from a while ago, but I am in the same position as dominic where I get the error from [appDelegare.myScript aMethod] that says _'Property myscript not found on object of type AppDelegate"_. For mine I did every step you put with my own code and it still says there is an error. And ideas? The only difference I can see is I put the code in `viewDidLoad` instead of `-(bool)application...` .